# Javascript go to ID minus some pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script to show/hide elements and go to selected ID. The only thing is it goes below the menu with the rest of the links so I need to go to ID minus about 50px so as to not go below the menu. How would I change this script to do this. I tried scrolltop() with no success. I'm quite a bum at javascript just so you know.

```
$('ul.tabs').each(function(){
// For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
// which tab is active and it's associated content
var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

// If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
// If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
$active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
$active.addClass('active');

$content = $($active[0].hash);

// Hide the remaining content
$links.not($active).each(function () {
  $(this.hash).hide();
});

// Bind the click event handler
$(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
  // Make the old tab inactive.
  $active.removeClass('active');
  $content.hide();

  // Update the variables with the new link and content
  $active = $(this);
  $content = $(this.hash);

  // Make the tab active.
  $active.addClass('active');
  $content.show();

});
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. What do you mean "*go to ID minus about 50px*"?

Comment: I don't see "go to selected ID" part in your code.

Comment: prevent the default action of the link then it won't jump to the hash - http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: can you build a fiddle for your code? As i can see your code is just adding/removing active class from each item in the menu and hiding (not scrolling) elements

Comment: here is an example: https://reedleyhrbs.com/event/sukkot/ when you click on #introduction it goes below the menu @LelioFaieta

Comment: here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4x7La64s/2/

Comment: @Pete i need it to jump to hash

Comment: Ah ok, I don't understand your problem then, surely your code will work if you had enough content?

Comment: @Pete if you go to https://reedleyhrbs.com/event/sukkot/ and then click on #introduction or any other tab on the menu, you will see that it goes below the menu. meaning a user would have to scroll up to go to another tab. I would like it to show the content for that tab but stay above the menu. does that make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('ul.tabs').each(function(){
    // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
    // which tab is active and it's associated content
    var $active, $content, tab = $(this), $links = tab.find('a');

    // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
    // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
    $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
    $active.addClass('active');

    $content = $($active[0].hash);

    // Hide the remaining content
    $links.not($active).each(function () {
      $(this.hash).hide();
    });

    // Bind the click event handler
    tab.on('click', 'a', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();

      // Make the old tab inactive.
      $active.removeClass('active');
      $content.hide();

      // Update the variables with the new link and content
      $active = $(this);
      $content = $(this.hash);
      location.hash = this.hash;

      // Make the tab active.
      $active.addClass('active');
      $content.show();

      $(window).scrollTop(tab.offset().top);
    });
  });
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4x7La64s/7/) (click on events link - should jump to top of menu)

Comment: Wow. I give the same answer, just not spoon fed, and get a long complaining comment that it's not what he wants. The joys of SO...

Comment: @JamieBarker the only reason for that is pete answered first... thanks for you help as well

Comment: @YobdDigital Don't get me wrong, I'm happy for him to get the answer accepted (my answer referenced his comment), it's just the hilarity that I gave the same answer except mine was rejected because it didn't include the requirement for URL changing, which at the time this answer was accepted, didn't include that either (which might I add wasn't pointed out in the question).

Answer (score 0):

As Pete mentioned in a comment, you want to prevent the default action. You don't need it to jump anywhere. If they've clicked on that navigation they're already going to be looking where the content is changing.

```
$(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault() // Add this line
```

That being said, if you're desperate for it to scroll down to the navigation upon every click of the navigation, you can add this to the bottom of the click listener:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("ul.tabs").offset().top
}, 1000);
```

Also if you're desperate to update the URL with the hash, you can force that too:

```
if(history.pushState) {
    history.pushState(null, null, this.hash);
} else {
    location.hash = this.hash;
}
```

Comment: i used to have that exact code but i need the #id in the address bar so that if there is errors in a form on one of the tabs when the page reloads it goes to the correct tab. As I said to pete if you go to https://reedleyhrbs.com/event/sukkot and then click on #introduction or any other tab on the menu, you will see that it goes below the menu. meaning a user would have to scroll up to go to another tab. I would like it to show the content for that tab but stay above the menu.

Comment: @YobdDigital See update for the address bar updating.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually quite easy. See this snippet:

```js
$('nav a').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
  var offset = $("#goto").offset().top - 50;
  $('body,html').scrollTop(offset);
});
```

```css
nav, div {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background: #999;
}
div {
  height: 100vh;
  background: whiteSmoke;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav><a href="#goto">The Goto Solution</a></nav>
<div></div>
<div id="goto">Top</div>
```

Just prevent the default, add your own hash and *after* that, go to the desired position.